# Divs Sit on top of each other on resize (HTML CSS)

Tags: css, html, resize

I'm currently doing a project for university where I have to make a simple website using css/html. I'm trying to resize one of my pages but when I do the various elements (Photo,Table and Box with text) all sit on top of each other instead of moving below each other like they do on all of my my other pages.

HTML(Relative to the sections playing up):

```
    <aside id="Name">
    <h3>Michael Freeman </h3>
    </aside>


    <aside id="Photo">
    <img src="images/me.jpg" alt="Picture of me" /> 
    </aside>

    <section id="Table">
    <table>
    <caption>My Timetable</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday </th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8:30</td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td>Database Analysis and design</td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td>Introduction to .net programming</td> 
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10:30</td>
        <td>Internet Technologies((lab))</td>
        <td>Database Analysis and design((lab))</td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td> 
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
    </tr>   
        <tr>
        <td>12:30</td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td>Internet Technologies</td> 
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2:30</td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td> 
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4:30</td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td> 
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5:30</td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
        <td>Introduction to programming.net</td> 
        <td class="emptydata"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>



    </section>
</article>
```

And the css:

```
Table{
height:4%;
Width:8%;
Color:#080000;
Margin-right:auto;
Margin:auto;
Text-align:center;
Margin-bottom:10%;
Margin-left:auto
}
tr{
border: 2px solid #080000;
}
td
{border:2px solid #080000;
background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
td.emptydata
{
background:#080000;
}
.emptydata:hover
{
background: red;
}
#Name
{Background-image:url(Images/Back.jpg);
text-align:right;
float:right;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
Margin-top:5%;
Border: 3px Solid #080000;
Font-size:150%;
Padding:1%;}
#Photo
{height: 4%;
Width:10%;
Float:left;
Padding-right:10%;
Margin-left:auto;
Margin:auto;
Border: 10px groove black;}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean sorry? My naming conventions?

Comment: @Kaleon Normally people write CSS properties in lower case. In fact, I had never seen CSS with capital letters, and some CSS syntax highlighters don't work with them.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll fix that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Kaleon is something like this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv2vX/show)** you want?

I used  `display:inline-block;`

take a look and tell me if it helps you.

I cleaned your code. Be aware to capitals in your CSS.

**EDIT**

as requested here is updated fiddle with code : **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv2vX)**

Comment: Yes this is precisely what I need it to do, 
I have actually tried to use the display:inline-block;
But for some reason it doesn't seem to be changing the layout at all for me. I'm sure it's some simple syntax or logic error on my behalf. May I look at the CSS you used? 

P.S I have fixed up those capitals (despite them all linking correctly to their identifiers) as I'm sure it would of drove my tutor insane!

EDIT: I'm an idiots and didn't realize the CSS was right there I will try get it working!

Comment: Hmm It seems the name and the picture now line up however the table still sits on top of the picture!

Comment: pay attention that I changed your HTML as well!

Comment: EUREKA! It's all sorted thank you so much with a little bit of playing around I got it to work! Will mark as accepted!

Comment: I changed your Name aside from before table to the end after table. Glad to help you.